# Unable to create IEnumerable on a class

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use below code in MVC and here is what I have done till now:

```
public class MoviesModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string Actor { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public MoviesModel Index()
    {
        MoviesModel myModel;
        string connectionString =
            "";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();

        com.CommandText = "SELECT [ID] ,[MovieName] ,[Actor] ,[Year] FROM [dbo].[Movies]";
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                myModel = new MoviesModel
                {
                    myModel.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                    myModel.MovieName = reader[1].ToString(),
                    myModel.Actor = reader[2].ToString(),
                    myModel.Year = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3])
                };
            }
        }

         con.Close();
        return myModel;
    }
```

But I am getting below error

```
cannot initialize class with a collection because it does not implement System.Collection.IEnumerable
```

Comment: You are updating the value of myModel in a loop. It will only get the value from the last row. Also you are not calling a stored procedure.

Comment: Also, you're not closing your database connection. [Using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx): use them!

Comment: When I am building my solution I am getting this error. @Joel Yeah ! I need to do that.. I was writing the code and I stuck as soon as I see the error.. I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: @Joel I have modified the code.. Thanks. Perhaps, I am learning ASP.NET MVC 4 and this is just for my learning and understanding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The compilation error you're getting comes with a file name and a line number, and I guarantee those things are not pointing at any of the code you've quoted.

I take that back, actually. I think this might be the source of your compilation error (telling us what line the compiler was complaining about would have helped).

```
myModel = new MoviesModel
{
    myModel.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
    myModel.MovieName = reader[1].ToString(),
    myModel.Actor = reader[2].ToString(),
    myModel.Year = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3])
};
```

That's not the right syntax. Inside the curly brackets is the code that will be run in order to initialize `myModel` - you can't refer to `myModel` inside the brackets, because it doesn't exist until after the code in the brackets has finished executing. Fortunately, you don't need to, because this is the syntax for setting those properties:

```
myModel = new MoviesModel
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
    MovieName = reader[1].ToString(),
    Actor = reader[2].ToString(),
    Year = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3])
};
```

More broadly, I'll go out on a limb and guess that what you really want to do is return a collection of MoviesModel objects instead of a single MoviesModel object that happens to be the last movie in the result set. The code to do that would look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var models = new List<MoviesModel>();
    string connectionString = "";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var com = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        com.CommandText = "SELECT [ID] ,[MovieName] ,[Actor] ,[Year] FROM [dbo].[Movies]";
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var myModel = new MoviesModel
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    MovieName = reader.GetString(1),
                    Actor = reader.GetString(2),
                    Year = reader.GetInt32(3)
                };

                models.Add(myModel);
            }
        }
    }

    return View(models);
}
```

As an aside, `Convert.ToInt32` is a pretty inefficient way to get something that's already an integer in the database, and in the reader. The `GetInt32` method will perform better.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistakes.. I do understand my question was bit stupid :)
This is really a great answer with explanation